# Routing and relative paths

Tags: php, codeigniter, path

CodeIgniter and many other PHP frameworks rout URLs,
e.g. if default controller is root.php then both URLs will work

```
website.com/
website.com/root
```

if controller has a function 'login' then this URL is valid

```
website.com/root/login
```

This is very handy, but the HTML template that used to work in first example, doesn't work in the second, e.g. this relative path is no longer valid

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheets/style.css'/>
```

and instead I have to use

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='../stylesheets/style.css'/>
```

Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make the styleshhet path relative to the rooot directory of the site I would think it would work in both cases, i.e.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css'/>
```

Comment: When the path is "relative to the root directory" it is called an _absolute_ path.